# Add date/time to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, datetime

How can I add the current date and time (the date and time set on the server) to a MySQL table?

Answer (score 11):

Pretty sure there's a `NOW()` function... [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer.. More on this @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to add it to the table or just to the result set?  You can add NOW() to the field list of any query to do that.

If you just want to know what time the server thinks it is try:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

Edit: the original of this answer erroneously used "GETDATE()" 'cause I totally missed the MySQL tag.   Matt Solnit called me on it, and rightly so.

Comment: The GETDATE() function does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: My bad.  I've gotten so used to all the MS* questions here I just missed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                             DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Answer (score 0):

use timestamp. easiest way, current_timestamp